# GAE - Maximum admins allowed

Tags: google-app-engine

I've added 15 persons to my GAE app and then I got this error: "Only 15 maximum admins allowed per application."

I do not see in the documentation that GAE has a limitation of this type, is a configurable setting?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the limit is not configurable.

From also seeing the [issue](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8412) you filed in the tracker, I'm guessing you're using the `VIEWER` permission to allow access to an admin-only page. To scale this to additional users, you'll need to use Google Account authentication and an ACL system of your own creation.