# Google App Engine's 15-person admin limit is too low. Easy solutions?

Tags: google-app-engine

I was surprised to hit the error from Google App Engine re: "A maximum of 15 admins is allowed for this application." (Google Docs does not have such a limit, for example.)

I've heard some solutions for bypassing this limit including creating my own ACL system based on Google accounts (e.g. [GAE - Maximum admins allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293594/gae-maximum-admins-allowed)), and moving to Google Cloud Storage and using their ACL system.

Would like to have a simple solution that allows me to keep my existing appspot.com URL with minimal refactoring.

Could Google please relax this limit? For example, allowing more "Viewer" roles etc.?

Otherwise, could someone point to a tutorial / example for how to bypass this limit with minimal refactoring?

I have a lot of static HTML pages restricted to admins and it would be nice to keep that structure. Am even thinking of creating a new shared Google account just so more people can access things (though of course this is also suboptimal).

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: You do realize that admins in this context can just start deleting stuff through the admin console.  Shouldn't you structure your application in such a way that developer/core admin is different from other classes of user and have some application level access control

Comment: well, admin in the context I was using it includes "Owner", "Developer" and "Viewer". "Viewer" should not be able to delete stuff...

Comment: correct, but as you noted you now have more users than are supported.  The minute you share accounts you have no visibility.  In addition you even if at the console level they are classed as viewer they are still  presented as admin to your application.  This means you can't differentiate different roles.